# xampp not showing .png file with a "%" sign in name

Tags: php, html, xampp

This file,

```
<img src="site_imgs/my_black_sig_25%.png" />
```

is not displayed in my htm web page using Edge or IE11 (not tested other browsers) when using xampp (Version 7.1.9)

If I remove the % sign from the file name and the web page code the image is displayed as expected. Is this expected behavior in xampp?

(If I preview my web page directly in the browser the image is displayed as expected.)

Comment: I don't know if it is expected or not, but you should really avoid having a dollar sign in the name of your files. This character has a special meaning on the web.

Comment: maybe renaming the image file will help you